# order matters in styles components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I noted that the styled-Component/Wrapper approach below can go wrong as a Child component CSS may be overridden by its parent. I came up with a simplified sample below:

This is the Parent component and its Styled-Component Wrapper:

```
 import styled from "styled-components";

const Child = () => {
  return (
    <ChildWrapper>
      <div className="nice-box" />
    </ChildWrapper>
  );
};
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <ParentWrapper>
      <div className="nice-box" />
      <Child />
    </ParentWrapper>
  );
};

const ChildWrapper = styled.div`
  .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
`;

const ParentWrapper = styled.div`
  .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
`;



export default Parent;
```

BUT if you put "ChildWrapper" after "ParentWrapper" it works and the child will have its own

style!

How to prevent the parent's style to be used for the child?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's not a question.

Comment: @HenryWoody How to prevent the parent style to be used for the child?

Comment: Probably better to just just not reuse the same classname directly for a thing that needs a different style.

Comment: @KevinB   that's the whole point of using styled-components, not be worried about nameing!

Comment: You don't need to use a class name with styled-components if you want the style to only apply to that particular element

Comment: @someone did you try the below option to see if it resolves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I believe that the issue could be resolved by useing the "direct chlid" selector (`>`):

```js
const ChildWrapper = styled.div`
  > .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
`;

const ParentWrapper = styled.div`
  > .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
`;
```

then the order of the styled components shouldn't matter

Answer (score -1):

To achieve expected result, add &&&(to get higher specificity) to the nice-box class of ChildWrapper to avoid overwrite

```css
const ChildWrapper = styled.div`
  &&& .nice-box {
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
`;
```

Sample working code for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-blackwell-gk6tfx?file=/src/Child.js

Reference link for more details from official documentation - https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity